# How to break v-for loop in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this `v-for` loop an my vue.js app:

```
  <div v-for="(word, index) in dictionary"> 
     // break if index > 20
     <p>{{word}}</p>
  </div>
```

I want to break out of the loop after rendering 20 words. How can I achieve this?
I looked at the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) but did not see anything about this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can manipulate the array before loop start

```
<div v-for="(word, index) in dictionary.slice(0,20)"> 
    <p>{{word}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that will work for an array, but not for an object.  I would use this method myself if it's simple, but if there's any more logic than this or if it's an object, I'd use a computed method.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a computed value for your truncated dictionary (e.g. it is better to prepare data for rendering):

```
computed: {
 shortDictionary () {
   return dictionary.slice(0, 20)
 }
}
```

...

```
<div v-for="(word, index) in shortDictionary"> 
   <p>{{word}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point. But for the sake of curiosity, I'm still wondering if there is any way to do it at `v-for` level?

Answer (score 5):

For this scenario, this solution works best for me.

```
<div v-for="(word, index) in dictionary" v-if="index <= 20"> 
    <p>{{word}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: no longer a good solution as vue now complains if you use v-for and v-if on the same 
html element.

Answer (score 0):

To do this at the v-for level, create a data object with the limit and compare it to index to control v-for with v-if.

```
  <div v-for="(word, index) in dictionary" v-if="index<=limit"> 
         // break if index > 20
         <p>{{word}}</p>
</div>

    <script>
export default{
   data(){
     return{
         limit: 20 }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the ability to use v-for with a range, here is a solution that does not involve creating a new array via splice or using a computed:

```
<div v-for="i in Math.min(dictionary.length, 20)"> 
  <p>{{dictionary[i-1]}}</p>
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.slice` and `Math.min`  functions:

```
<div v-for="(word, i) in dictionary.slice(0, Math.min(20, dictionary.length))"> 
   <p>{{word}}</p>
</div>
```

Using computed methods:

```
computed: {
 firtsElements () {
   return this.dictionary.slice(0, Math.min(20, this.dictionary.length))
 }
}
```