# How to break a v-for loop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a code segment that i have mentioned below. I have used vuejs with vuetifyjs.

```
 <v-data-table v-bind:headers="headers" v-bind:items="uniqueSubjects">
                            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.index+1 }}</td>
                                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ month[new Date(props.item.daily_date).getMonth()] }},{{ props.item.student_id }}</td>
                                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.subjects.subject_name }}{{ props.item.subjects.id }}</td>
                                <template v-for="n in 31">  
                                    <template v-for="(mark,index) in resultsList">
                                        <template v-if="new Date(mark.daily_date).getDate() == n && mark.subject_id == props.item.subject_id && mark.student_id == props.item.student_id">
                                            <td class="text-xs-center">
                                                {{ mark.daily_marks }}
                                            </td>
                                        </template>
                                        <template v-else-if="index>=resultsList.length-1">
                                            <td class="text-xs-center">-</td>
                                        </template>
                                    </template>
                                </template>
                            </template>
                            <template slot="pageText" slot-scope="{ pageStart, pageStop }">
                                From {{ pageStart }} to {{ pageStop }}
                            </template>
                        </v-data-table>
```

I want to break my `<template v-for="(mark,index) in resultsList">` loop when the internal `v-if` condition is true.
Here i want to search the inner loop from first to last.I want to break the loop if the data is matched depending on the given condition.and then i want to do it again and again.
How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break v-for loop in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429774/how-to-break-v-for-loop-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to break `v-for`. It is better to create a computed property in your component and filter your data there to pass only needed data to `v-for`.

For example:

```
// ... your component code
computed: {
   validResultsList() {
     return this.resultsList/* ... your filtering logic ... */;
   }
}
// ... your component code
```

And then in your template:

```
<template v-for="(mark,index) in validResultsList">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @bsalex. Can you please provide an example if possible?

Comment: @Sakil How about you try yourself?

Comment: Have tried bro and still trying but no luck you know :( :( @George

Comment: @Sakil Part of asking questions on stackoverflow is showing us what you've tried.  This way we don't waste time trying the same things you did.  Or we can point out things you've done slightly wrong