# Limit result on a v-for with vueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Simple problem, i have a members list where i iterate through it with a v-for.

How can i limit the results and only show the first 2 ?

```
members = [ {id : 1, name: 'Franck'}, {id : 2, name: 'Sophie'}, {id : 3, name: 'Bob'}]
<div v-for="member in members" :key="member.id">
    <p>{{ name }}</p>        
</div>
```

Just want to know if it's feasible from template ? Otherwise i know that i can use a computed properties that filtered it and i just have to loop through the results of my filtered array

Comment: As for now there is no way to break a loop in Vue.

Better watch this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101822/how-to-break-a-v-for-loop-in-vuejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice()` in the template if you prefer to not use a computed property. I would though choose to have a computed property, if for nothing else, I like to handle all logic in script instead of template. But as said, you can use slice:

```
v-for="(member, index) in members.slice(0, 2)"
```

A forked **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vje6tc3/)** that was provided by @Raffobaffo in a comment.

Comment: Exactly. But then you find some user like down here that downvote you because they like to fill their pages with empty divs.

Comment: @Raffobaffo Oh, and right, I see now that it was a fiddle provided by you, not OP. corrected that in my answer. But now I was thinking I'll delete my answer, didn't see that you had used slice in computed property. That is the way I would go, for sure.

Comment: Great. Thanks for giving me credit too!

Comment: @Raffobaffo not to mention the users that want to re-iterate over the entire list every re-render :P

Comment: this is the answer to my question but effectively for cleaner readability, i'll use computed property as i stated before. It was more to see if there was something i missed on the documentation. 
Thanks to @Raffobaffo and AJT82 for the time they took to debate on this one

Comment: Great, so if you do not accept my answer at least upvote please for the time spent :)

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

After some discussions here, lets divide the answer in two:

A fast, not super correct way but still referred [inside vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if)
Use a v-if and set and index in the v-for.

```
<div v-for="(member, index) in members" :key="member.id" v-if="index < 3">
    <p>{{ name }}</p>        
</div>
```

else, the most correct way is to create a computed property returning just the elements you need:

```
  <template>
       <div v-for="member in justTwoElements" :key="member.id">
         <p>{{ name }}</p>        
      </div>
  <template>

  ....
  computed: {
       justTwoElements: function(){
           return this.members.slice(0,2);
       }
   }
```

This latest solution is more indicated when your data entry is huge, the benefits of using it instead of the first solution are well explained [here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)

I hope this helps to give you the correct path to follow

Comment: You shouldn't include your v-if to the same element as your v-for

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential

Comment: @procoib the same link is in my answer, with an explanation

Comment: Where is the example for <template v-if>? All im seeing is the example of putting a v-for and v-if in the same element lol